# Fetch only Live Photos using Photos Framework dosen't work

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, photosframework, phasset

I'm trying to fetch only Live Photos out of the device albums.
I found this Objective C code, but for some reason when converting it to Swift to doesn't compile.

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(mediaSubtype == %ld)", PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoLive];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"creationDate" ascending: NO]];
PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType: PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: options];
```

Swift:

```
 fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaSubtype == %ld", PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive)
```

throws compile error :

```
 Argument type 'PHAssetMediaSubtype' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArgType'

Any suggestions?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't supply a Swift enumeration value to that method - it needs a long (as is implied by the `%ld` format string), so use

```
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaSubtype == %ld", PHAssetMediaSubtype.PhotoLive.rawValue)
```

to access the underlying integer value of the enumeration value

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Clean and elegant!